iframe.contentWindow.postMessage not working in incognito mode
I have a widget script (widget.js) deployed on an AWS S3 bucket. This script creates an iframe with its src set to http://localhost:5000.
I embedded widget.js using script tag in my web app. Once the iframe is loaded I am sending message  postMessage to http://localhost:5000
document.getElementById('iframe').addEventListener('load', function () {
      this.contentWindow.postMessage({ appKey: '123abc', type: 'app-key' }, 'https://main.d1imq0p99lrf.amplifyapp.com/');
    });

Problem:
The postMessage works as expected in normal browsing mode but fails in incognito mode. I suspect this might be due to stricter privacy settings or cookies issues in incognito mode, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause.
Environment:

Browser: Chrome (latest version)
Operating System: macOS Ventura

Solutions Tried:

Ensuring correct target origin in postMessage.
Checking browser console for errors (none found).
Disabling browser extensions.
Simplified the code to isolate the problem.

Expectation:

The post message should work even in incognito mode


Please share the error code or screenshot for the POST request from the Network panel.

@N.Raj no error is there on the console or from the network response

I would try changing local host to the actual IP address of your local machine. The browser places extra restrictions on iframes with local hosted pages for some reason
